# pycharm not autocomplete all torch.Tensor methods

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm, torch

```
os:window 11  
pycharm:2023.02,CE  
anoconda:2023,07-1
```

I recently use pycharm to develope my python project.
I use anaconda as my project interpreter, but when I type some simple code,I can not get autocomplete,for example[image]
what's confusing me much is that I know torch.Tensor object has method size(),but I can't get autocomplete from pycharm,but when I run the program,it works fine.
I found size() method in  `torch._C._TensorBase.py`, which `torch.Tensor` inherent from.not just `size()` method,all method defined in `torch._C._TensorBase.py` can't get autocomplete
how could I get autocomplete? is there anything wrong about my configuration?

I reinstall different version pycharm and torch several times,and get same result

Comment: sorry about the Typesetting, I'm new here

Comment: seems to be a new pycharm behavior, solved by reinstall an earlier version pycharm,

Comment: Furthermore, it doesn't recognize the correct operators (<, +, *, etc.) defined in _TensorBase, so type hinting becomes broken and annoying.

Comment: A similar issue is reported here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-49401/PyTorch-tensor-comparison-is-falsely-considered-a-boolean